# Swiping Over an Actor in Scene2d

Tags: animation, input, libgdx, actor, scene2d

I want to detect if an input swipes across an actor in my program. I have found other similar questions online but the answers weren't that much helpful. What I want to happen is that whenever a swipe enters the boundary of my actor, an Image pops up. I would also like to mention if in case needed that this actor is animating and its code comes from another class extended as an Actor. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just mentioned the answer to your question. Use InputListener enter to detect whenever an input enters the borders of your actor. Here's the code for that:

```
Actor.addListener(new InputListener(){
            public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor fromActor){
     //Enter what you want to happen when a swipe enters your actor boundary.
}
```